# What is the difference between `select` and `phi` in LLVM IR?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, ssa

For example, I have a C code:

```c
void foo(int x) {
    int y;
    if (x > 0) {
        y = 1;
    } else {
        y = 2;
    }
    // do something with y
}
```

To simplify this code in LLVM IR level (where `y` can be put in the register rather than stack), I can use `select`:

```
define void @foo(i32 %x) {
    %result = icmp sgt i32 %x, 0
    %y = select i1 %result, i32 1, i32 2
    ; do something with %y
}
```

However, if I use `phi`, the code becomes much longer:

```
define void @foo(i32 %x) {
    %result = icmp sgt i32 %x, 0
    br i1 %result, label %btrue, label %bfalse
btrue:
    br label %end
bfalse:
    br label %end
end:
    %y = phi i32 [1, %btrue], [2, %bfalse]
    ; do something with %y
    ret void
}
```

As far as I know, the only advantage of `phi` over `select` is that `phi` supports more than 2 branches, while `select` only supports 2 branches. Beyond this situation, is there any other situation where `phi` is better than `select`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Operands of `select` are `Value`s only, while `phi` operands are pairs of `Value` and `BasicBlock`.

Another difference is that `phi` can turn the control flow of a function, while `select` only allows choosing between two values based on the boolean value. Roughly speaking, `select` corresponds to the `?:` ternary operator, and `phi` corresponds to C `switch` statement with many cases.